# Designing a Data Warehouse/ Star Schema - Choosing facts

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

Consider a crowdfunding system whereby anyone in the world can invest in a project.

I have the normalized database design in place and now I am trying to create a data warehouse it (OLAP).

I have come up with the following:

[image: Star Schema]

This has been denormalized and I have chosen Investment as the fact table because I think the following examples could be useful business needs:

- Look at investments by project type
- Investments by time periods i.e. total amount of investments made per week etc.

---

Having done some reading (The Data Warehouse Toolkit: Ralph Kimball) I feel like my schema isn't quite right. The book says to declare the grain (in my case each *Investment*) and then add facts within the context of the declared grain.

Some facts I have included do not seem to match the grain: *TotalNumberOfInvestors, TotalAmountInvestedInProject, PercentOfProjectTarget.*

But I feel these could be useful as you could see what these amounts are at the time of that investment.

Do these facts seem appropriate? Finally, is the *TotalNumberOfInvestors* fact implicitly made with the reference to the Investor dimension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think "one row for each investment" is a good candidate grain.

The problem with your fact table design is that you include columns which should actually be calculations in your data-application ( olap cube ).

**TotalNumberOfInvestors** can be calculated by taking the distinct count of investors.

**TotalAmountInvestedInProject** should be removed from the fact table because it is actually a calculation with assumptions. Try grouping by project and then taking the sum of *InvestmentAmount*, which is a more natural approach.

**PercentOfProjectTarget** is calculated by taking the sum of *FactInvestment.InvestmentAmount* divided by the sum of *DimProject.TargetAmount*. A constraint for making this calculationwork is having at least a member of DimProject in your report.

Hope this helps,

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Either calculate these additional measures in a reporting tool or create a set of aggregated fact tables on top of the base one. They will be less granular and will reference only a subset of dimensions.

*Projects* seem to be a good candidate. It will be an accumulating snapshot fact table that you can also use to track projects' life cycle.